# How can I plot multiple dataframes on the same figure from an excel sheet using pandas?

Tags: python, excel, pandas, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple y-values(Force) and x-values(displacement) on the same figure. I usually find it easy when the x-values are constant for all the plots but with it varying, I haven't found a way to work it out. Please, I would like some help with the best way to approach this.

I have attached a picture of the data I am trying to plot. The three samples are have varying x-values and y-values.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qAZt7.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Solution

Let us assume that you have three dataframes: `df0`, `df1` and `df2`. Additionally, let us assume that in each dataframe you have two columns: `x` and `y`. If we make a list of these dataframes, `dfs = [df0, df1, df2]`, then you could plot all three of them on the same plot as follows.

The solution here is divided into two sections:

- Makinng dummy data (this is only needed for reproducing some dummy data).
- Plotting the dataframes (you will need to use this code).

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

%matplotlib inline
%config InlineBackend.figure_format = 'svg' # 'svg', 'retina'
plt.style.use('seaborn-white')

# Make Dummy Data
N = [100, 125, 150]
P = [[3, 2.2], [5, 3.7], [2, 4]]
dfs = list()
for n, p in zip(N, P):
    x = np.arange(n)
    y = p[0]*x**p[1] + np.average(p)
    df = pd.DataFrame({'x': x, 'y': y})
    dfs.append(df.copy())

# Make Plots
#dfs = [df1, df2, df3]
for i,df in enumerate(dfs):
    plt.plot(df['x'], df['y'], 
             linestyle='--', 
             alpha=0.8, 
             label='df{}'.format(i))

plt.legend(loc='best')
plt.show()
```

**Output**:
[image]